# Appending data in UITextField programmatically

Tags: iphone

I am creating a report & printing the same on a UITextView.My report has some titles and there respective subtitles. I am printing 1st title then its subtitle & then second title and its subtitle and so on. I want different font and font sizes for the titles and subtitles.
But the problem is the text field always prints the last subtitle.If any one know solution to this problem,let me know.

Here is what i have dome in my .m file

```
     - (void) printData {
       // data is UITextView object
       [data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
       NSString *title = @"TITLE" ;
       data.text = title;
       [data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15]];
       NSString *subtitle = @"SUBTITLE" ;
       data.text = subtitle;
     }
```

Comment: can u post the code you are using

Comment: Here is what i have dome in my .m file

- (void) printData {
        // data is UITextView object
        [data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
        NSString *title = @"TITLE" ;
        data.text = title;
        [data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15]];
         NSString *subtitle = @"SUBTITLE" ;
         data.text = subtitle;
}

Comment: Edit the question instead of providing the code in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would Use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`, as it is build for long text.

If you just keep calling the method text of either `UITextField` or `UITextView`, the currently residing text will be replaced with your last text. To avoid that you have to append new text to the text that is already residing in the `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

```
NSString *appendThisText = @"subtitle";
self.myTextView.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.myTextView.text, appendThisText];
```

As for the fonts. The font property applies to the entire `UITextField` and `UITextView` content.

What you could do in your case is to use `UIWebView` and render your text using HTML.

Comment: Thanks Cyprain for the answer. UIWebView is a much better solution for the customization.

Comment: Yes it is. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

`[myTextView setText:[myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"my string"]];`

Or with a \n line break:

`[myTextView setText:[myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\nMy string"]];`